# Weird online basemap behavior

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, labeling, arcgis-online-basemaps

I'm using ArcMap 10.2.2 in a remote server and I have added the online "Imagery with Labels" base map to my map (first picture). When I turn it off the labels (and the light dashed line) remain visible though, and even by removing the basemap from the table of contents, they don't disappear (second picture). Why?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Strange..have you tried to refresh the view?

Comment: Yes I have. I wonder if it has to do with the fact I'm using a remote version.

Comment: I think it is likely

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "I'm using remotely ArcMap" and "I'm using a remote version"?  I think this is a critical detail to include in your question.

Comment: What do you mean by Remotely Arcmap? and please if the ArcGIS Online basemap is public, put the URL in your post?

Comment: I don't know how to get the URL, I just added it through the the add base map button. Anyway, I'm using ArcGis through a server, it's not on desktop.

Comment: If you check the properties of the layer, you can find the  url

Answer (score 3):

Some Basemaps add a 'Reference' layer with them, which is separate in your Table of Contents.  Look in your TOC to see if there is a 'Reference' layer - it's added at the top of the order (so the labels show up on top of other features) and is separate from the imagery layer.